# Simple Function in python

Tags: python

I was wondering if this code can be coded better in terms of semantics or design. Should I return the LOS as numbers? should I have the constants be read from the db in case the user or I want to change them in the future?

```
def get_LOS(headway = None, frequency = None, veh_per_hr = None):
  if frequency != None and headway = veh_per_hr == None:
    headway = 1 / frequency

  if headway!= None or veh_per_hr != None:
    if headway 10 < or veh_per_hr > 6:
      return 'A'
    elif 10 <= headway < 15 or 5 < veh_per_hr <= 6:
      return 'B'
    elif 15 <= headway < 20 or 3 < veh_per_hr <= 5:
      return 'C'
    elif 20 <= headway < 31 or 2 < veh_per_hr <= 3:
      return 'D'
    elif 31 <= headway < 60 or 1 <= veh_per_hr < 2:
      return 'E'
    elif headway >= 60 or veh_per_hr < 1:
      return 'F'
    else:
      return 'Error'
```

Comment: Edit so that the code is readable and correct.  Also you might want to explain a little more about what get_LOS is actually trying to accomplish and what the values 'A' - 'F' mean.

Comment: This code can't run in this form.  `headway = veh_per_hr == None` is illegal as is `headway 10 <`.  Please be sure that code you want reviewed has a small chance of actually running.  And if it doesn't run, please use StackOverflow to find and fix the problems.

Comment: The current question title is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def get_LOS(headway = None, frequency = None, veh_per_hr = None):
```

You have no docstring. That would helpful in explaining what the parameters are doing.

```
  if frequency != None and headway = veh_per_hr == None:
```

When checking wheter something is none it is best to use  `is None` or `is not None`

```
    headway = 1 / frequency
```

The problem is that if someone passes frequency along with one of the other parameters, this function will go merrily onwards and probably not even produce an error. I recommend having a get_LOS_from_frequency function which takes the frequency and then calls this function.

```
  if headway!= None or veh_per_hr != None:
    if headway 10 < or veh_per_hr > 6:
```

I'm pretty sure that won't compile

```
       return 'A'
    elif 10 <= headway < 15 or 5 < veh_per_hr <= 6:
      return 'B'
    elif 15 <= headway < 20 or 3 < veh_per_hr <= 5:
      return 'C'
    elif 20 <= headway < 31 or 2 < veh_per_hr <= 3:
      return 'D'
    elif 31 <= headway < 60 or 1 <= veh_per_hr < 2:
      return 'E'
    elif headway >= 60 or veh_per_hr < 1:
      return 'F'
```

I'd store these values in a list which makes it easy to pull them from configuration at a later date if neccesary.

```
    else:
      return 'Error'
```

Don't report error by returning strings. Throw an exception, or at least assert False.

How I'd do this:

```
import bisect
def get_los_from_frequency(frequency):
    return get_los(1 / frequency)

HEADWAY_LIMITS = [10, 15, 20, 31, 60]
VEH_PER_HR_LIMITS = [1,2,3,5,6]
GRADES = "ABCDEF"

def get_los(headway = None, veh_per_hr = None):
    if headway is None:
        headway_score = len(GRADES)
    else:
        headway_score = bisect.bisect_left(HEADWAY_LIMITS, headway)

    if veh_pr_hr is None:
        veh_pr_hr_score = len(GRADES)
    else:
        veh_pr_hr_score = len(GRADES) - bisect.bisect_left(VEH_PR_HR_LIMITS, veh_pr_hr)

    return GRADES[min(headway_score, veh_pr_hr_score)]
```

Comment: This was very helpful especially with  the bisect and lists :)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than:

```
if frequency != None and headway = veh_per_hr == None:
    headway = 1 / frequency
```

You should move the assignment out of the if statement:

```
if frequency is not None:
    headway = veh_per_hr
    if veh_per_hr is None:
        headway = 1 / frequency
```

This will make it more clear what you're doing without making a future reader do a double-take when they see the assignment embedded in the middle of an if statement.  It also might point out that this might be better written as:

```
headway = veh_per_hr
if veh_per_hr is None and frequency is not None:
    headway = 1 / frequency
```

As an aside, if you want to know why to use `is None` or `is not None` instead of `== None` or `!= None`, one reason is:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.Timer('x=1; x != None').timeit()
0: 0.18491316633818045
>>> timeit.Timer('x=1; x is not None').timeit()
1: 0.17909091797979926
```

Another could be the fact that it's much easier to accidentally type `=` instead of `==` and have an unnoticed assignment slip by in your conditional (which is another argument for never doing that on purpose as a later maintainer might mistake that for a typo).